# displaying the input value of txtbox1 to txtbox2

Tags: javascript, php

I want: when I enter in the txtbox Enter amount, then I submit the button , the amount I enter in textbox1 which is inputValue it this display in the txtbox which is  totAmountPaid

html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Enter Amount:</label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="inputValue"   value="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12"> 
     <label>Total Amount Paid:</label>
         <input type="text"  class="form-control" 
         readonly="readonly"id="totAmountPaid" value="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 ">
      </br><button class="btn btn-primary col-md-6" type="button" 
               onclick="myFunction()" >btn</button>
</div>

script
function myFunction(){
 var paidAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputValue").value);
document.getElementById("totAmountPaid").value =  paidAmount.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: what is the relation to php?

Comment: `script` is that your actual syntax?

Comment: *Tap, tap, tap* - did you leave/logout? Edit: Well, I have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including your JS before you are trying add the onClick handler?

If you load the js beforehand it should work fine.

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lyspxwvu/1/

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
     var paidAmount = parseFloat(document.getEle`enter code here`mentById("inputValue").v`enter code here`alue);
    document.getElementById("totAmountPaid").value =  paidAmount.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
<div class="col-md-12"> 
     <label>Total Amount Paid:</label>
         <input type="text"  class="form-control" 
         readonly="readonly"id="totAmountPaid" value="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 ">
      </br><button class="btn btn-primary col-md-6" type="button" 
               onclick="myFunction()" >btn</button>
</div>
```